# what's the "default" theme for (Progress)Dialogs in android?

Tags: android, android-styles

I can create a ProgressDialog like this:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Hi");
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
progressDialog.show();
```

Looks great, but I want to change a couple aspects - **and only a couple aspects** - of the ProgressDialog that is created using the code above.  **Everything else should remain the same**.

Let's say I want to change the text color and disable the background dimming.  I know I can do this programmatically, but **I'd like to use a custom defined style**.  I can then apply that style:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.MyProgressDialogStyle);
...
```

So the question is, what should I use as the parent, such that the "default" style being used on the device is unchanged?  Obviously I want the solution to be portable so that it works on all devices.

```
<style name="MyProgressDialogStyle" parent=?????>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

All answers I've seen so far seem to use different themes as the parent.  Does that mean that there's no real way to achieve what I'm looking for?  Is using a style the wrong approach in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You properly want to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert`

Comment: That doesn't work:

Before, no style applied:  https://snag.gy/hkU2K8.jpg
After, with Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert:  https://snag.gy/xXCHvf.jpg

Comment: That's not very specific. How do you know it's not working? Try removing the android: prefix.

Comment: yeah sorry I pressed "enter" before and it inserted my comment before I was able to supply the before/after images.

Comment: removing the android: prefix leads to an aapt error:  No resource found that matches the given name: attr "backgroundDimEnabled".  Same for textColor.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's not working? The style is definitely applied. If that's not the textColor wanted by you, try using `textColorPrimary`, `textColorSecondary` and so on. Refer to [this style](https://hastebin.com/faduyuliti.xml) which shows you quite well what you can use as keys.

Comment: I don't believe you read my entire question.  I don't want anything to change from whatever the default is, except for (in this case) text color and background dimming.  Applying the Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert changes more than I want, which is made obvious by the before/after photos.

Comment: Have you tried replacing Light by DayNight (Or removing it entirely)? That's the first thing I'd try considering your dialog is *light* after applying the style... If that doesn't changed anything you are out of luck, because that are the parent styles you can use.

Comment: yes i've tried, it either changes more than i want to change or it doesn't look the same on all devices.

Comment: The last thing you can try is not using AppCompat. After that there are no more parent styles you could extend.